# 2nd law question

Tags: entropy

The reaction CO2 + 4 H2 <==> CH4 + 2 H2O (liq) at 25oC is downhill with a gibbs energy of -31 kcal/mol. It has a negative entropy of -98 cal/K. Thus an isolated system of the two starting gases should go to equilibrium on the basis of the Gibbs energy value, but the process would then violate the 2nd law. What am I missing here?